# How to Dynamically Route in ASP.net 6.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I have a problem where I want to route to a page like so:

site.com/Company/StackOverflow
site.com/Company/Microsoft

I want to take the name of the company from the Route and pass it as parameter into my IActionResult Index() function so that I can retrieve it from a database. How could I do this so I don't have to explicitly call out the Route

This is what I currently have, but what comes into my controller is CompanyName = null

In my Program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "company",
    pattern: "{controller=Company}/{action=Index}/{CompanyName}");
```

In my CompanyController:

```
public IActionResult Index(string CompanyName)
{
    string test = CompanyName;
    //Fetch info for CompanyName and build model
    //Return view with model
    return View();
}
```

If Possible, I'd like to avoid a URL that has the following
site.com/Company?CompanyName=Microsoft.com

Comment: `app.MapControllerRoute(name: "company", pattern: "company/{CompanyName}", defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" });`

Comment: To match your configured routing the company name would need to be part of the request path, not a search paramter `site.com/Company/Microsoft.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the defaults parameter in the MapControllerRoute method.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "company",
    pattern: "{controller=Company}/{action=Index}/{CompanyName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" });
```